# Is it valid to write $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} = \infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, infinity

AFAIK the limit of a term does not exist if that term does not converge, but I haven't found a suiting question here yet.  This probably is a double of a similar question.

Comment: Alfe, do you mean lines, instead of limes?

Comment: No …?  Your question baffles me.

Comment: @yiyi "limes" is Latin, in English, the word is "limit".

Comment: I am going to google for what limes mean in math. THought it might be a typo, sorry.

Comment: No problem, since I'm not so fluent in English mathematics, questions like these point out things to me I didn't know yet.  So the case here with _limes_ vs. _limit_.  Thanks to @Daniel Fischer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assigning a value to divergent limits is not entirely standardized among mathematicians.

One reasonable standard is that $\infty$ is not a number, while we want all limits to be numbers, so $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}$ simply doesn't exist.

Another standard, probably more common, tries to distinguish functions that grow arbitrarily large, from limits that behave erratically and don't converge.  Then $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}=+\infty$.  The $+$ is necessary to distinguish this case from its negative.

Comment: That $+\infty$ thing is interesting.  Does it mean that $\infty$ without the $+$ can mean positive as well as negative?  In particular, can one write $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$ even if that can be positive _or_ negative?

Comment: That is a reasonable standard, that as far as I know nobody uses.

Comment: @vadim, I disagree. $\infty$ _means_ $+\infty$ by default, unless otherwise specified. Just as $99$ means $+99$. The standard way to write Alfe's assertion is $\lim_{x\to 0}|\frac1x| = \infty$.

Comment: @TonyK, you've missed the point of Alfe's comment.  The limit he gave is of $\frac{1}{x}$, not $|\frac{1}{x}|$, which is $+\infty$ from one side and $-\infty$ from the other.  His suggested notation is $\infty$ to indicate this situation.  As for your notion that $\infty=+\infty$, that's reasonable but by no means universal.

Comment: No, I haven't missed the point, I just disagree with it. You can't write $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1x = \infty$, it's just wrong under the default interpretation.

Comment: Just for completeness:  What about $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x} = ±\infty$?

Comment: That too is a reasonable standard, that as far as I know nobody uses.  There is pretty much universal agreement that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ is undefined.  It's already something of an abuse to define $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{x^2}$; however this situation comes up often enough that it's worthwhile to make this special case.  The situation you describe is not important enough to make extra cases in our notation for.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0 } f(x) = \infty$ means that $f(x)$ diverges to positive infinity as $x$ tends to $0$.

Comment: Well yes, obviously $-$ but what does _that_ mean?

Answer (score 1):

It is valid to write $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x^2} = \infty$. However, this merely notation for the following: For all $M \in \mathbf{R}$ there is $\delta \in \mathbf{R}$ such that if $0<|x|<\delta$ then $\frac{1}{x^2} > M$, essentially the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ grows without bound as $x$ approaches $0$.

Comment: You need to say "if $0 < |x| < \delta$".

Answer (score 0):

$\infty$ is a special case, but the notation is standard. The statement

$$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$$

means that the closer $x$ approaches $a$, the larger $f(x)$ gets. In symbols:

For all $M > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $0 < |x-a| < \delta \implies f(x)>M$.